# Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1" after build project Haskell

Tags: haskell, build, haskell-platform, haskell-stack

After connect to .cabal file some package(for example `text`) and after build project throw Exception: `Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1"`.

For building project, I'm using haskell-stack, command: `stack build` in terminal. (I'm using MacOS  Capitan)

Some line .cabal file:

```
executable Real-exe
hs-source-dirs:      app
main-is:             Main.hs
ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
build-depends:       base
                 , Real
                 , text
default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Without(text package) all working.

Full Error:

```
"Real-0.1.0.0: unregistering (dependencies changed)

Real-0.1.0.0: configure

Configuring Real-0.1.0.0...

Real-0.1.0.0: build

Preprocessing library Real-0.1.0.0...

[1 of 1] Compiling Lib ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-    osx/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/Lib.o )

In-place registering Real-0.1.0.0...

Preprocessing executable 'Real-exe' for Real-0.1.0.0...

<command line="">: cannot satisfy -package-id text-1.2.1.3-  3718968f98d5614ccdc45c27d4e8b0a1

(use -v for more information)

-- While building package Real-0.1.0.0 using:

/Users/ximet/.stack/setup-exe-cache/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.4.0/ build lib:Real exe:Real-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"

Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1"
```

Comment: in .cabal using only space (not tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such errors may be due to an out of date package cache. `ghc-pkg recache` run at the command line may help.

Failing that, executing `stack --no-system-ghc --install-ghc build` instead of the usual stack command line will just tell stack to not use the installed libs at all, which may also help.